# Can i access the Database Data in Ethereum Smart Contract to transfer the funds?

Tags: contract-development

Can anyone suggest whether the described architecture is not violating the principle of blockchain? Let's say we have a huge data set of PolicyHolder, which has many attributes. There are so many regulators involved in the process of claim.Lets say Entity A(Authentic) has sent some data to the Insurance Company(which holds the data set of policyholders). The company has to validate whether the data that is coming is satisfying all the attributes of the (policyholder) if it is satisfying the amount has to be transferred else reject the request. If doing all this of checking attributes in the Smart contract is very costly. So is it okay to do this in off-chain and then write the Transaction in Blockchain(Ex-P234, has paid $400 to Address: 9090909090 for the accident). Is there any better way to do this?

Can we use oracalize to fetch the data from Database and do the validation conditions here and write the transactions in Ethereum Blockchain?

Comment: Why would you want to use Ethereum blockchain for this?

Comment: You would use IPFS or Swarm to store eg JSON documents (https://github.com/ethersphere/swarm) and store the hash pointers on chain only.

Comment: Likewise you can use Whisper https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Whisper
To send requests for claim verification.

Comment: I am doing proof of concept for Insurance domain using Blockchain.As there are so many intermediates involved in the entire process of Insurance claim and other stuff,with this technology we want to cut the number of intermediates and make the things more transparent.